# Why does a Unicode PHP file generate a line break?

Tags: php, unicode, include, line-breaks

I have this code in my admin.php file:

```
 <?php include("include/php/auth.inc.php"); ?>
 <?php if (user_Type() != "admin") {header("location: index.php"); exit(0);} ?>
 <?php include("include/php/admin/admin.inc.php"); ?>
 <?php include("header.php"); ?>
 <?php include ("menu.php"); ?>
 <?php include ("admin_Panel.php"); ?>
 <?php include "footer.php" ?>
```

At line 3 I included a PHP file named `admin.inc.php`, this file contains only some functions and does not contain any HTML tag or any character outside `<?php` and `?>`. When I change  the file encoding to UTF-8 (with Notepad or other editors using save as) this file generates a line break in the output.

Comment: Try to save it as `utf8 without BOM`

Comment: how can i do it by notepad++ or aptana studio 3?

Comment: in Notepad++ in the main menu row there is `Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`

Comment: thank's, problem fixed by removing BOM, plz send your solution as an answer for converting this question usefull for others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to resave your file as `UTF-8 without BOM`

in Notepad++ in the main menu row there is `Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`

Comment: This work perfectly. Do you why should we use the "without BOM" option ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no lines or even blank spaces before or after the  php tags.